# Cant get data to observable in knockout js

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am sending a ajax request to get data, with this code.

```
self.emailNotification = ko.observable();


    self.checkNotificationOfEmail = function (){
        $.ajax({
               type: 'POST',
               url: BASEURL + 'index.php/myprofile/checkNotificationOfEmail/' + auth,
               contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
           })
           .done(function(data) {
               alert(data);
            self.emailNotification(data.on_off);


           })
           .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
               self.errorMessage(errorThrown);
           })
           .always(function(data){               
           });
    };
    self.checkNotificationOfEmail();
```

The problem is when I alert ( data) I get object object, and when I try to push that data which I am getting into self.emailNotication observable, Its not working. Dont know what I am doing wrong. And when I try to alert self.emailNotification(data.on_off); I get undefined.
When checking on console
[image]

Comment: Have you tried using `console.log()` instead of `alert()`?

Comment: @cl3m uploaded a picture

Comment: Response is an array so you need to use data[0].on_off

Comment: @AleksandarGajic so how do I push it to the observable ?

Comment: i've added an answer so youll need just to do it like this  self.emailNotification(data[0].on_off)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use other tools than `alert` for debugging, either `console.log` or preferably even the debugger. This will give you loads more information.

Your specific issue is probably caused because the structure of `data` is not what you expected: it contains an *array* of items. Other than that your code is fine. See:

```js
var BASEURL = "/testing/", auth = "faketestvalue";

function ViewModel() {
  var self = this;

  self.emailNotification = ko.observable();

  self.checkNotificationOfEmail = function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: BASEURL + 'index.php/myprofile/checkNotificationOfEmail/' + auth,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
      })
      .done(function(data) {
        alert(data);
        self.emailNotification(data[0].on_off);
      });
  };
}

// Fake ajax stuff (synchronously):
var fakeData = [{ on_off: true }];

var $ = {
  ajax: function(options) {
    return {
      done: function(callback) {
        callback(fakeData);
      }
    };
  }
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<button data-bind="click: checkNotificationOfEmail">checkNotificationOfEmail</button>
<hr>
Debug info:
<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root, null, 2)"></pre>
```

Answer (score 2):

Response of your ajax call is an array so

```
self.emailNotification(data.on_off);
```

is undefined, you need to access the first item in collection

```
If (data && data.length) {
    self.emailNotification(data[0].on_off)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But Jaeron posted it before you, so I guess its right to actually accept his answer since he was first...But Thanks alot!